# How to share ASP classic session variable from ASP to VB6?

Tags: iis, dll, vbscript, asp-classic, vb6

I'm working on a project developed in classic Asp with vb script that calls a VB6 dll library with the `Server.CreateObject` method.

I created a **session variable** in ASP and would like to read it from **VB6 dll**.

I searched a lot on the web but I didn't find solutions.
This is data related to the user connected, then stored in a session variable.

**My goal is to get to know the connected user by the VB6 dll.**

Comment: Doesn't the VB6 DLL have properties that allow you to pass the required arguments? That's usually how it works with DLL's and I don't think you'll get it to work any other way...

Answer (score 2):

There are basically two approaches, though it's been a *long* time since I've dealt with either, so this is almost completely from memory, with a little help from some Microsoft documentation pages that are still hanging around:

1. When you call the sub or function in your VB6 DLL, pass along the information you're looking for like any other argument. This is probably the most intuitive since it works like any other method call.

   ```
   Dim objStuff
   Set objStuff = Server.CreateObject("Stuff.MyStuff")
   objStuff.DoSomething Session("ASessionVariable")
   ```
2. Since you're using the `Server.CreateObject` syntax, VB6 can hook into the IIS object model directly. In the VB6 project references, you need to add the "COM+ Services Type Library" and the "Microsoft Active Server Pages Object Library". (If you don't have them on your development system, you might need to install IIS on it.) You then use the `GetObjectContext()` function to access the ASP objects from within your component. See the documentation on "[Creating Visual Basic COM Components for ASP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524912%28v=vs.90%29)".

   ```
   Public Sub DoSomething() 
       Dim objContext As ObjectContext 
       Dim objResponse As Response 
       Dim objSession As Session
       Set objContext = GetObjectContext() 
       Set objResponse = objContext("Response") 
       Set objSession = objContext("Session")

       objResponse.Write "Session value: " & objSession("ASessionVariable")
   End Sub
   ```

   And then within your ASP:

   ```
   Dim objStuff
   Set objStuff = Server.CreateObject("Stuff.MyStuff")
   objStuff.DoSomething
   ```

   You might need to play around a bit, since as I said I haven't done any of this in forever, and I can't find documentation on exactly what's in that ObjectContext, but I think you ought to be able to get it to work. The first option is probably a lot easier, though.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, a user helped me in a forum, I put the link below.

*You can define two Subs, "OnStartPage" and "OnEndPage" in your class. For example:*

```
Dim vSC As ScriptingContext

Public Sub OnStartPage(SC As ScriptingContext)
    Set vSC = SC
End Sub

Public Sub OnEndPage()
    Set vSC = Nothing
End Sub
```

*(You'll need to add a reference to "Microsoft Active Server Pages Object Library" to the project)*

*IIS calls this subs automatically when your object is created (Server.CreateObject) and destroyed (Set Obj = Nothing). This way you don't need "DataFromASP" Sub. The ScriptingContext object gives you access to all ASP objects (Server, Response, ...)*

[Link vbforums.com](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?877435-How-to-share-ASP-classic-session-variable-from-ASP-to-VB6)

Thanks to Leo