# VB6 Error :Object variable or with block variable not set

Tags: vb6

I get this

> "Object variable or with block variable not set" inside 'dblog' sub function

in this line , I guess its with 'm_Session'

`If iType >= Int(m_Session("_SysParam_LogLevel")) Then`

My Code

---

```
Private m_Session As ASPTypeLibrary.Session

Public Function InitializeSite(Optional intCheckMode As Integer = 0) As Boolean

InitializeSite = False

Dim cmd As ADODB.Command

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

DBLog "Initializing started - "

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    With rs

        .ActiveConnection = DBConnection

    end with

end function

Public Sub DBLog(ByVal sTxt As String, Optional ByVal iType As Integer = 0, Optional ByVal sCategory As String = "DEBUG")

  'On Error Resume Next

    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command

   If iType >= Int(m_Session("_SysParam_LogLevel")) Then

        Set cmd = New ADODB.Command

        With cmd

            .ActiveConnection = DBConnection

        End With

  End If


  Set cmd = Nothing

  On Error GoTo 0

End Sub

Property Get DBConnection() As String

DBConnection = IIf(Not IsNull(m_Session("_SysParam_DBConnection")), m_Session("_SysParam_DBConnection"), "")

End Property
```

Please help me moving forward.

Answer (score 2):

Function InitializeSite should also initialize variable m_Session before calling DBLog sub, or you could modify code in DBLog sub adding

```
If m_Session Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
```

at the beginning.

Or you could initialize variable m_Session adding this sub to your class

```
Public Sub OnStartPage(SC As ASPTypeLibrary.ScriptingContext)
  Set m_Session = SC.Session
End Sub
```

Take a look at [How to share ASP classic session variable from ASP to VB6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57372455/how-to-share-asp-classic-session-variable-from-asp-to-vb6)

Comment: Hi Smith,Thanks for answering , but every time i encounter with  m_session ,I get this 'Object variable or with block variable not set error.

Comment: I also have the code with 'm_session' below Dblog call function ,like so     ...                                                                                           DBLog "Initializing started - " & About, 1, "DLL"

m_Session("_System_EngineFile") = App.EXEName
m_Session("_System_EngineFileDescription") = App.FileDescription                                                               
please help...

Comment: As @Smith said, you need to `Set` m_Session somewhere.  A few suggestions were given in the post.

Comment: Hi Smith and Brian, Is it okay if we write this way instead of making use of another sub function Dim m_Session Dim SC As ASPTypeLibrary.Session and inside 'dblog'(function) , setting this way ' set m_Session=sc

Comment: One more thing guys..now that Im using 'ASPTypeLibrary.Session' , do I have to refer to any other references apart from 'COM+  Service Type Library' , 'Microsoft ActieX dataObject 2.0 Library' , 'Microsoft Active Server Pages Object Library' ? Please suggest.

Comment: Just press Ctrl+F5 and if there's no 'User-defined type not defined' error - references are OK.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your first line of code with:

```
Private m_Session As new ASPTypeLibrary.Session
```

Comment: Yes ,I tried that piece of code too, then I get error saying 'Compile Error: Invalid Use of New Keyword' .